# in joomla 3.X : How to change or edit Component Url in html page source code?

Tags: joomla-3.x

For the security reasons, How we can change or edit the Joomla3.x Component name inside HTML source code by changing the Component URL.

For example; When we display the HTML source code for any page that uses Joomla components, we will find the component name inside the component url as :

```
<link href="/components/com_XXX/...." rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the components name is part of a link used by the browser to load resources then I don't believe you can change the name without breaking the connection with the resource.

You could use a plugin that compresses or consolidates your scripts and CSS into single files for performance reason as they will or may remove the names, using their own random filename. Something like JCH Optimise comes to mind here.

You mention for security reasons so if you are trying to implement 'security by obscurity' then you might find using a reputable site level firewall product type of extension to help protect your resources is a better approach than trying to hide which components you have installed. Akeeba and RS have suitable firewall products and I am sure a search on JED will find you more.